# Empty line on ssh login

Tags: ssh, debian

I have just received the login information for a new vServer running Debian 5.0 (amd64). Whenever I log in I get an empty line:

```
markus@neon ~ $ ssh flour

markus@flour ~
```

I don't know where this line comes from and I don't want it to be there. To debug this I put `foo` in /etc/issue.net and set the `Banner` option in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` accordingly. Then I put `echo bar` in my `.bash_profile` as the first line. The result is this:

```
markus@neon ~ $ ssh flour
foo

bar
markus@flour ~ $
```

I don't know which files are used between the `Banner` and `.bash_profile`. Could someone give me a hint, please?

Comment: what does `cat /etc/motd` say?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `PrintMotd` is set to `yes` (or is commented out - `yes` is the default), I would guess that there's a blank line in `/etc/motd`. Debian by default has quite a verbose MOTD, and it sounds like someone's edited the file and deleted all the lines by hand, leaving the last line empty.